# How to remove bottom panel in Gnome Shell

Tags: 11.10, gnome, network-manager, gnome-shell-extension

How do you remove that obnoxious pseudo-invisible bottom panel in Gnome Shell in 11.10? Network Manager is especially annoying, as it will place a large "Network Disconnected!" tab that won't go away until I click on it, as if I wasn't already aware I no longer had an Internet connection.

In 10.04, it used to make a small growl modal in the upper right hand corner that gradually faded away. I really miss that. How do I get that back and permanently remove the bottom panel? I'm aware of various PPAs offering shell extensions, but I haven't been able to find one offering this explicit functionality.

Comment: The network manager bug is http://pad.lv/883443

Answer (score 3):

An [enterprising developer](http://ubuntu.igameilive.com/2012/01/how-to-remove-bottom-panel-message-tray.html) has claimed to come up with just this solution - for me it does work with a small tweak described below.

[image]

To get this to work with 11.10:

Extract the source.

Rename the folder from `gnome-shell-extension-remove-bottom-bar` to `remove_bottom_bar@k2z.com`

Then in this folder edit the file `metadata.json`

Replace the contents of this file with the following, save and close:

```
{
    "shell-version": [ "3.2" ],
    "uuid": "remove_bottom_bar@k2z.com",
    "name": "Remove bottom bar",
    "description": "Removes the Message tray (bottom bar). I recommend to use with gnome-shell-gnome2-notifications extention by rcmorano.",
    "url": "http://www.k2z.com", 
    "version": 3
}
```

Then move the folder to the location `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

Logout and login and activate the extension using `gnome-tweak-tool`

Answer (score 1):

Notifications can be moved to the top right corner using [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/243/shell-osd/).

BTW, if you're looking for lots of extensions, you better check the [Gnome Shell Extensions website](https://extensions.gnome.org/) instead of using PPAs.

Comment: This does move the notifications to the upper right. Unfortunately, they're still "sticky" and don't go away until clicked...

Answer (score 0):

If you hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right click on the panel you can delete the panel.